# What program as an replacement of metriCAD for pre-measurement of construction works reading .dwg CAD files?

Tags: linux, cad

What program would you recommend as an replacement of metriCAD? The program should read .dwg files (CAD files) and run on 32 bit computer. It should also run on Unix-based system like Ubuntu, Linux Mint or Debian or, in last case, on Windows XP.

In specific, I need a program supporting the preparation of a Takeoff (bill of quantities) based on 2D documentation in DWG and DXF format (especially I need to import of the DWG files). The program should automate the calculation of the length of:
polylines, arcs, surface areas limited by any polygon and built on their  plan side surfaces and solids.

It should also be equipped with functions for Takeoff (pre-measurement of) stairs, roofs, and line works.

In MetriCAD, Takeoffs are compiled in the form of tables, which can be used to work with systems for cost estimation (I should be able to export the calculations).

And, ideally, I wish the program to be free-of-charge. It's for learning purposes.

Comment: What features of Metricad do you use? Do you need to import Metricad files or also write them back? Please read our [question quality guidelines](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).

Comment: Thank you @Gilles. I have added some information to the topic. I don't need to import Metricad files allthough it would be great to have that option but it is not neccessary.